# css3-mediaqueries.js cause IE to hang

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using css3-mediaqueries.js to support IE8 and 7 but when I load the page the brower hang and stop working.

I use mobile first process and my  media query as like

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

}
```

Any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and 8 do not suppport media queries. Modernizer doesn't help here either.  I just put ur media query into my current project which uses modernizer and renders to IE7&8 (to do a simple header{ color:red } ). Sorry, but it didn't help. Google, FF, of course do fine.

Any chance u can use a max-width in ur logic since IE7&8 aren't common on screen sizes under 1024? IE7&8 usually just ignore the queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a widespread problem as per this thread:
https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/issues/detail?id=8

I use respond.js from here https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond